# ChartPanel not fiting the size of a JPanel (JFreeChart)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart

I'm just using the method `setSize` of the ChartPanel. For some reason, it fails to work. Here's the code:

```
    mostSoldPanel = new JPanel();
    chartTabbedPane.addTab("Mais vendidos", null, mostSoldPanel, null);
    mostSoldChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Mais vendidos", "Produtos", "Quantidade", createDataset(),
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(mostSoldChart);
    mostSoldPanel.add(chartPanel);
    chartPanel.setSize(mostSoldPanel.getSize());
```

Here's the visual result:

[image]

Comment: Consider changing `mostSoldPanel = new JPanel();` to `mostSoldPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());` and get rid of the `get/setSize` calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely cause is the fact that `JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`, which is allowing the child components to use their own `preferredSize` to when been laid out.

Consider changing `mostSoldPanel = new JPanel();` to `mostSoldPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());` and get rid of the `get/setSize` calls

Comment: Worked like a charm. It seems that my Java is getting a bit rusty. Thank you!